# Google maps not show in release mode android

Tags: android, google-maps

I have a problem with my google maps API. In debug mode it's working fine. But when in release mode i got blank maps. i have tried to change SHA1 from debug keystore to release keystore. any idea for my problem?

Comment: These problem generally occurs only when you are using the different keystore

Comment: Generate correct SHA1 from release keystore file and add in console with correct package name.I hope it work.

Comment: i have generate SHA1 from my release keystore and i get SHA1 and put it to credetial in google developer. but it didn't work

Comment: i use different  keystore between debug and release. but for release keystore it use .jks extension file @RavindraKushwaha

Comment: If correct then cross check your console generated APIKEY in code.

Comment: i have check the APIKEY in my code but it's same with APIkey in google developer

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Add the apikey to debug>res>values>google_maps_api.xml 
then add release>res>values>google_maps_api.xml.

Then check it work or not.

Maybe you have 2 google_maps_api.xml files, one in the app/src/debug/res/values folder and the other in the app/src/release/res/values folder, but only the debug one contains your API key.

Comment: Its saves my day. Thanks

Comment: I just copy pasted the API key in debug to my release>res>values>google_maps_api.xml. and then i went to google developer console>API manager>credentials, and added my release SHA-1 certificate fingerprint to the my api key.(under Restrict usage to your Android apps section)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. There is problem with your key . Regenerate key and try.

Comment: regenarate key? or APIKEY?

Comment: There are two types of certificates. i.e for debug and release. You have to use the release certificate for production. For a complete guide please refer https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/signup#release-cert

Answer (score 1):

Did you generate the private api key ? it happened with me when i create private api key and i was using different keystore to make a build.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are using debug keystore for generating Google API key for map.

(Assuming you are using Android Studio)
Do following steps:

1. Generate SHA 1 fingerprint using, using your .jks file for Release mode.

   a. Open Android Studio

   b. Open Your Project

   c. Click on Gradle (From Right Side Panel, you will see Gradle Bar)

   d. Click on Refresh (Click on Refresh from Gradle Bar , you will see List Gradle scripts of your Project)

   e. Click on Your Project (Your Project Name form List)
   Click on Tasks/Android

   f. Double Click on signingReport (You will get SHA1 and MD5 in Run Bar)
2. Use this key in google_maps_api.xml.
3. Sync and generate signed APK.
4. Your Map is working now.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone is facing the same issue, I will share my solution...
I am creating an app and I finally got at the point to release it. So I tried to run on the release mode and I got the information that I needed to set the signingConfigs for the build variants release. Once I did it, and configured my proguard-rules.pro file the app was running, great! but the map wasn't showing.

I found people talking about the keystore and SHA1 credentials end everything but it wasn't clear for me yet. So I recorded that I has to set a key to make my map work on the build variants debug and everything came together.

So what I learned is that debug and release uses different SHA1 credentials and a Key can have more than one credential related to it.
When I set the key for the google maps following this link https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/get-api-key I got the SHA1 credential for the debug, so to make my map work I had to get my SHA1 credential from release and add it to my key at the...

Google Cloud Platform Console >  "Select Your Project" > "Click on the Hamburger Icon on the Top Left" > APIs & Services > Credentials > "Click on your credential used for the debug mode" > Restrict usage to your Android apps > "add the new SHA1 credential from release mode"

Now the point is, how to get my SHA1 credential from release mode?
If you have already set you signingConfigs for the build variants release you probably got a keystore.jks file. With this file you can get your credential by going to your bash and type..

keytool -list -v -keystore YOUR.PATH.TO.THE.KEYSTORE.FILE -alias YOUR.KEYSTORE.ALIAS

Then they will ask you the keystore password and done! 
Now you can copy and paste your SHA1 credential from release mode to your key at the Google Cloud Platform Console. =)